# Error while child component receiving data from parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components, angular2-inputs

I passed data prom parent to child

```
`<tag-editor[item]="item"></tag-editor>`
```

Item here has data

Child component:

```
export class TagEditorComponent implements  OnInit, OnChanges {
@Input() private item: Tag;
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.item)
}
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log(this.item)
}
```

But i got only 2 `undefined`.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like `item` in the parent component is undefined.

Comment: `editor [item` would **space be required** here. just a guess.

Comment: what is a parent component

Comment: Parent component has data.

Comment: @MaxKarpovets "Parent component has data" that's quite unlikely. Please show the code how you assign the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Try this : 
import {OnInit, SimpleChanges, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
export class TagEditorComponent implements  OnInit, OnChanges {
@Input() private item: Tag;
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.item)
}
ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges) {
  if(typeof changes['item'] !== 'undefined'){
  console.log(this.item)
  }
}
```